# How to offer to users several workflows to complete a task

Tags: lists, workflow, wizard, customisation

Suppose we are making a medical software to **support doctors to perform medical examination** on the patients and store results in the system.

What is unusual in this case, is that doctors often have **several specialisation** - e.g. one can do several types of examinations - e.g. cardiological and dermatological examinations. Each type of examination consist of tests, but not all of them are performed every time. Also doctor can later perform any test separately, and that test is not necessarily part of any type of examination. For example, at one appointment doctor can perform cardiological examination, dermatological examination and then dental test.

My current solution is to offer different workflows at the first screen and then later allow additional additional tests:
[image]

**What would be better ways to support those different workflows (dermatology, cardiology, etc.) and allow customization ?**

Comment: How many potential 'tests' are there? It seems like there could be many.

Comment: Yes many, 10-30 per workflow, and >100 in total.

Answer (score 1):

#### Once a user creates a custom workflow, allow them to save it as a template for reuse.

If the potential for large amount that they may need access to, but use infrequently, allow the to pin or favorite a common workflow.

**Tests that are outside a workflow**

It sounds like tests are also a separate object. You could have a landing page that separates them into 2 sections. A doctor could Create a custom workflow, or 'Add a test' (selecting from a preexisting range of tests. Once a test is added for the first time, it could live in the list below for quick access.

Is it important to have a history of the tests created? It seems like that would be useful for a doctor to see what they've ordered. If so, you could have a history section.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSEPK3.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Nice inputs, thanks Mike. I like the idea of "starring" frequently used tests and workflows.
All tests (both that are part of a workflow and standalone) need to be performed and the results recorder (I guess you are referring to this as "history").

So the problem that remains is how to "merge" standalone tests and workflow tests results and explain this concept to user.

Comment: If I understand this, for the history view, you could merge them in a table, with a 'Diagnostic Type' column, with either Workflow or Test (there's probably some term more familiar to to the users than Diagnostic Type).

Comment: We were considering this too. The problem with that approach is that the workflow is just an easier way to complete a set of tests at once. And we want to show to user that a workflow/examination consist of several tests. E.g. examination X = tests A + B + C, and after that we don't want to make user want to add test B manually via search box. How would you explain composition to the user?

Comment: Ah, I see. What if you used a master layout as cards, where you could put the included tests inside the workflow name? That way they can read it. And maybe not have separate 'workflows' and tests. Could they just create a single test or a 'compound test'? I'm not sure this helps; you have an interesting problem space to deal with.

Comment: Sorry for radiosilince - its been 1 y since I last logged in here :D Cards with subtests looks like a great self-explanatory idea!

Comment: That last comment pretty much solves the question. How we could share the insights with the community? Should I update question, or would you mind updating the sketch in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Permissions!

I would say depending on what specialization the doctor has, he/she would be permitted to take examinations according his/her specialization. This would mean he/she would be only allowed to take the tests of the examination(s) he/she could perform. So depending what specialization you are in, the permissions will show the doctor a different screen to begin with. Kind of like an Active Directory system.

In the test screen, the doctor should be manually be able to add tests to the examination form when needed. Every time the doctor would perform a necessary test, he/she would add a test to the form, which he/she needs to fill in when the test is performed.